# Is there a simpler way to get the argument type list for a snowflake procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to transfer ownership of snowflake procedures post clone to a new Role.

To do this I'm using a procedure which works through all objects from the database.information_schema.xxxx views.

The procedures are problematic though, the SHOW PROCEDURE has a column which shows the procedure signature as just argument types, but the information_schema.procedures view shows the actual parameter name as well as its argument type, which if passed into a GRANT command does not work - the grant expects the Argument Type signature only, not the parameter names :/

SHOW PROCEDURE ARGUMENTS => PROCEDURE_NAME(VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES.ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE => PROCEDURE_NAME(P_PARAM1 VARCHAR)

I eventually came upwith this which was fun, but feels rather complicated, the question is - have I missed a simpler approach?

```
SELECT procedure_name
     , concat('(',listagg(argtype, '') within group (order by argindex)) cleanArgTypes
  FROM (SELECT procedure_name
             , argument_signature
             , lf.index argindex
             , lf.value argtype
          FROM rock_dev_test_1.information_schema.procedures
             , lateral flatten(input=>split(decode(argument_signature
                                                  ,'()','( )'
                                                       ,argument_signature
                                                  ),' ')
                              ,outer=>true) lf
          WHERE lf.index/2 != round(lf.index/2)
        )
GROUP BY procedure_name
         , argument_signature
ORDER by 1,2;
```

cleanArgTypes => (VARCHAR)

This takes the overspecific argument_signature splits it into an array using space as a delimiter, then laterally flatten the return set into rows, discard the parameter names (always at an even index) then groups by parameter name and signature and uses ListAgg to put the parameter argument types back into a string.

Small wrinkle in that () doesn't work, so has to be shifted to ( )

Whilst I enjoyed dabbling with some of Snowflakes Semi-structured capabilities, **If there was a simpler approach I'd rather use it!**

Comment: Apologies I don't have enough reputation to upvote answers, hopefully another reader will.. thank you for the input though, always good to see alternative approaches especially if it gives tighter, neater orore efficient code. A colleague used a UDF with RegExp to solve this, and as I needed to reuse it for functions, that is the approach adopted atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the same code, but it doesn't need to be nested, I swapped from the arg_sig (the input) to using the SEQ of the split, but mostly the same still:

```
SELECT p.procedure_name
    ,'( '|| listagg(split_part(trim(t.value),' ',2), ', ') within group (order by t.index) || ')' as out
FROM information_schema.procedures as p
    ,table(split_to_table(substring(p.argument_signature, 2,length(p.argument_signature)-2), ',')) t
group by 1, t.seq;
```

for the toy procedures in my stack overflow schema I get:

| PROCEDURE_NAME | OUT |
| --- | --- |
| DATE_HANDLER | ( DATE) |
| TODAYS_DELIVERY_AMOUNT | ( VARCHAR) |
| ABC | ( TIMESTAMP_NTZ, TIMESTAMP_NTZ, VARCHAR) |
| ABC_DAILY | ( ) |
| STRING_HANDLER | ( VARCHAR) |

Comment: Not sure your method copes with overloaded procedures but I do prefer the way you have worked the input string, feels cleaner and more efficient to break into "name argtype" and then get argtype. I've missed something though, I thought lateral flatten was required for converting the array into rows and joining to itself, but looks like that's not so.?

Comment: @MattPrince The simple way is to test. But it does becasue t.seq is the row input to the flatten. Thus every inout row is keep separate.

Comment: Ah, I see, split_to_table is a table function that does a lateral flatten, and seq is the input row, index the order or rows generated within a sequence. I understand now, in that case if I could upvote this answer I would, its a cleaner, tighter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this. Here's an alternate way:

```
with A as
(
select PROCEDURE_NAME, split(replace(trim(ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '()'), ','), ' ') ARGS
      ,ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE
from   test.information_schema.procedures P
)
select PROCEDURE_NAME
       ,listagg(VALUE::string, ',') as ARGS
from A, table(flatten(ARGS))
where index % 2 = 1
group by PROCEDURE_NAME
;
```

You could also use a result scan after the `show` command to get the name of the procedure and argument signature in a single string:

```
show procedures;
select split("arguments", ')')[0] || ')' as SIGNATURE from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

Comment: I think you've also lost overloaded procedures, but otherwuse I see the first as a valid alternative approaxh and the second as an even better alternative. Initially I shied away from using show,/result scan but then had to use it for transferring ownership of tasks which don't seem to have a matching information schema view.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to pull out the list of procedures from the information schema with properly formatted argument signature, using a combination of splitting the string up with SPLIT, putting each value on a separate row with LATERAL FLATTEN, filtering to only get the data types using the INDEX, then re-grouping with LISTAGG. No subquery needed either.

```
SELECT PROCEDURE_SCHEMA || '.' || PROCEDURE_NAME || '(' ||
REPLACE(LISTAGG(C.Value,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.INDEX),'(','') AS "Procedure"
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES,
LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => SPLIT(ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE,' ')) C
WHERE INDEX % 2 = 1 OR ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE = '()'
GROUP BY PROCEDURE_SCHEMA, PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE
```